# Bypass authentication in development mode (.NET Core)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API with authentication. I'm using Identity.

Each time I want to test the API with Swagger, I need to create the token, copy/paste and executing the request.

How can I avoid this annoying manipulation?

Comment: could you please let us know which authentication scheme you are using now? when we create an API via the template, it only provides 2 scheme https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnHCc.png

Comment: by the way could you please check if [this blog](https://code-maze.com/swagger-authorization-aspnet-core/) helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did, simple, efficient:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();
}
else
{
    app.MapControllers();
}
```